# Migrate FSMO roles during FRS to DFSR migration

Tags: ntfs, dfs-r, fsmo

Hello everyone and I hope everyone is well.

I have a bit of a special case at one of my clients, we are in the middle of a migration from FRS to DFSR, (step 2) and have to go to step 3, eliminated. The customer would like to wait a little before this step.

So I would like to make progress on the migration of FSMO roles. But I can't find any information on the internet if I can cross this intervention with the migration from FRS to DFSR.

Concerning the technical data, we are talking about ten DCs, normal and RODC, distributed in Europe, Africa and America.

The biggest latency time between the DCs in terms of replication is 16min ~.

The DC that owns the FSMO roles and the one that has to host them are on the same site.

I did the necessary tests, dcdiag, repadmin, dfsrmig /getmigrationstate & /getglobalstate, on the different DCs, everything is ok and there are no errors.

Do you think I am taking a big risk by migrating the FSMO roles while the migration to DFSR is not completed but ongoing?

Thanks in advance,